# How can I create 1 minute candles for trading pairs in Python?

Tags: python, binance, candlesticks

I'm trying to figure out how to create a 1 minute candlestick for trading pair BTC-USD using the binance package in Python.

So far I can get this down:

```py
from binance.client import Client

candles = client.get_klines(symbol='BTCUSDT', interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE)

for candlestick in candles:
    print(candlestick)
```

But I'm not quite sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have used `Client` (capital-case) or at least the asynchronous equivalent `AsyncClient` to create `client`, then the following will print the most recent 1-minute candlestick. For example,

```
from binance import Client

client = Client(api_key = 'Enter Your Key', api_secret = 'Enter Your Secret Key')
candles = client.get_klines(symbol='BTCUSDT', interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE)

print(candles[-1])
print(f"\nLength of candles: {len(candles)}")
```

Output

```
[1650011040000,       # timestamp (opening time)
 '40203.99000000',    # opening price
 '40237.03000000',    # high price
 '40198.01000000',    # low price 
 '40198.01000000',    # closing price
 '20.07769000',       # volume
 1650011099999,       # timestamp (closing time)
 '807538.88381350',   # quote asset volume
 488,                 # number of trades
 '6.25446000',        # taker buy base asset volume
 '251560.61470140',   # taker buy quote asset volume
 '0']                 # ignore

Length of candles: 500
```

By default, `candles` will be a list of the last 500 1-minute candles (each candle itself represented by a list) for the `BTCUSDT` trading pair and you can specify a maximum of 1000 last 1-minute candles using the `get_klines` method. The most recent candles are at the end of the list `candles` and the oldest are at the beginning.

So your code (assuming you have used `Client` or `AsyncClient` to create `client`) should be printing all 500 of the last 1-minute candles starting from the oldest to the most recent.

The details of each element in a list corresponding to a candle can be found [here](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html?highlight=get_klines#binance.client.Client.get_klines). In particular, in the output above (showing the most recent 1-minute candlestick), the first element is the timestamp, the second element is the opening price, the third the high price, the fourth the low price, the fifth the closing price, and the other elements are not strictly components of a trading candle but are useful information nonetheless (e.g. volume).

By the way, if you do not want to be restricted to only the most recent 500 1-minute candles, you can make use of the `get_historical_klines` method which allows you to specify a start date/time and end date/time (still limited to 1000 candles per call).

Comment: Thanks a bunch Oda! Is there a way to exclude the field: Ignore and replace it with like the Symbol name or something?

Comment: Happy I can help @NewbieCode! I am not sure I quite understand. Can you please be a little bit more specific?

Comment: So in the output we have all those fields you listed. The last one is called #Ignore. How do I exclude that from the output response from the klines function? Or is it not possible and I have to do it via DataFrame or something?

Comment: `candles[-1][:-1]` would return the list corresponding to the most recent candle without the last element (the one I labelled `#ignore`). Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes perfect! Thank you : )

Comment: @NewbieCode No worries! Trade safe!